# FQL, Javascript, I need help with a multiquery, I'm not getting any response

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

this is my code

```
var user_stream = FB.Data.query(
        "SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id IN "
        + " (SELECT target_id FROM connection WHERE source_id=746744609 AND is_following=1)");

var friends = FB.Data.query("SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=746744609");

alert('before');
var result = FB.Data.waitOn([user_stream,friends], function () {
        alert('middle');
    });
alert('after');
```

I see the 'before' and 'after' pop ups, but never the middle one. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Could facebook be throwing me an error and I'm not catching it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, There is an error with your query response. Because facebook javascript sdk will not callback if there is some errors with response. You should use your browser's developer tool and check the response of your query. Are there any exception?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I changed this code a while ago. I appreciate you taking time to answer.